# Let $V$ be a vector space over field $C$ with inner product $<.,.>$ prove

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, vector-spaces

Prove that $$4(x,y) = |x+y|^2-|x-y|^2+i|x+iy|^2-i|x-iy|^2$$

While I was expanding the right hand side, I got confused with the $i|x+iy|^2$ part. I know that $ |x+y|^2=|x|^2+2(x,y)+|y|^2$ and $|x-y|^2=|x|^2-2(x,y)+|y|^2$ , but for $i|x+iy|^2$, does it equal to $i(|x|^2+2i(x,y)+|y|^2)$? or $i(|x|^2+2(x,iy)+|y|^2)$? I think both of them were wrong because the left hand side and the right hand side were not equal using them. What should be the right expansion of $i|x+iy|^2$? Thank you very much!!!

Here 4(x,y) is the inner product of x and y

Comment: I use (x,y) to represent the inner product of x and y

Comment: Please format your mathematical expressions using LaTeX, it makes it so much easier to read.

Comment: What is meant by $4(x,y)$?

Comment: @ErikMiehling it is the inner product of x and y